# document.createElement: el.size = "2%" not working

Tags: javascript, dom, createelement

I'm using the following:

```
el = doc.createElement("input");
el.size = "2%";
```

I get the error message (in Firebug): `Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount`.

It was working fine when I just injected the HTML rather than built the DOM properly, as below:

```
$rsc.html("<input name = 'myName' type = 'text' value = '" + myVariable + "' size = '2%' />");
```

Why is it not accepting the `2%` with createElement?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, everyone; you're all spot on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `size` attribute accepts only integers, not percents. It represents the maximum number of allowed chars to be typed in the input.
If you put that in your HTML, probably the % is ignored and the value is parsed as 2.

If you need to adjust the width of the input, then you can use `style='width:2%'`.

Comment: Thanks for a very comprehensive answer. Testing in Firebug shows that the `%` is being ignored; changing it to a straight 2 makes no difference (whereas changing it to 3 & 1 enlarges and narrows it respectively).

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately we need to be careful with HTML because the browser tries to parse whatever it can and we don't get any warnings.

Comment: Absolutely. This is a perfect example of that :)

Answer (score 1):

`size`property's unit is character (pure integer), there is not allowed to use any other units with `size`.
If you want to have `input`which width is 2%, you'll need to make this via `style`:

```
el.style.width='2%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Observation in chrome

```
   > var a = document.createElement('input');
   > undefined
   > a.size
   > 20
   > typeof a.size
   > "number"
   > a.size = "10"
   > "10"
   > a.size
   > 10
   > a.size = "1x"
   > "1x"
   > a.size
   > 20
   > a.size = "1%"
   > "1%"
   > a.size
   > 20
```

In Firefox

```
>>> var a = document.createElement('input');
undefined
>>> a.size
20
>>> typeof a.size
"number"
>>> a.size = 20
20
>>> a.size = "20"
"20"
>>> a.size = "2%"
Error: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount
[Break On This Error]   
a.size = "2%"
```

I think chrome safely ignores invalid integer values while firefox throws an error.